# AngularJS v1.3.5 - Page reloads on route change after npm install

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, npm-install, reload

I am facing an issue with AngularJS version 1.3.5 in my project. After performing an npm install with recent changes, I noticed that whenever there is a route change on my AngularJS page, the page reloads instead of once as expected. This issue was introduced suddenly after the new build and I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause.

Consider the following package.json file of my angularJs project
{
"name": "angular-mphrx",
"private": true,
"version": "4.0.1",
"description": "Basic Search implementation of webconnect in angular",
"repository": "https://github.com/sgrewal-mphrx/angular-mphrx",
"license": "MIT",
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.4",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
"@opentok/client": "2.21.2",
"ansi-html": "0.0.8",
"babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
"babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "0.10.0",
"babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node-babel-7": "2.0.7",
"browserify": "16.2.3",
"bufferutil": "4.0.1",
"clean-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "5.0.4",
"css-loader": "3.2.0",
"es6-promise": "3.2.1",
"expose-loader": "0.7.5",
"file-loader": "4.2.0",
"html-loader": "0.5.5",
"html-minifier": "4.0.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
"http-proxy": "1.13.3",
"loader-utils": "^1.2.3",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
"node-sass": "4.12.0",
"minimatch": "7.4.3",
"npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
"sass-loader": "7.3.1",
"style-loader": "1.0.0",
"terser-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
"vinyl-buffer": "1.0.1",
"vinyl-source-stream": "2.0.0",
"webpack": "4.39.2",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.6.0",
"webpack-cli": "3.3.7",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.8.0",
"webpack-merge": "4.2.1",
"yargs": "3.0.4"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot --progress --profile",
"lint": "eslint . --ext .js",
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config ./config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile",
"build-dev": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config ./config/webpack.prod.no.minify_uglify.js --progress --profile",
"pretest": "npm install",
"test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
"test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js  --single-run",
"preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
"update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
"preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
"protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
"update-index-async": "node -e "require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\/\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\s\S]*\/\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\n' + sed(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/,'sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map','app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');""
},
"dependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.8.3",
"angular": "1.3.15",
"bower": "1.8.13",
"angular-animate": "1.3.20",
"angular-bootstrap": "https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower/archive/0.14.3.tar.gz",
"angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.32",
"angular-encode-uri": "1.0.0",
"angular-file-md5": "0.1.0",
"angular-file-upload": "2.5.0",
"angular-google-analytics": "1.1.8",
"angular-gridster": "0.13.14",
"angular-i18n": "1.3.5",
"angular-loader": "1.3.20",
"angular-local-storage": "0.7.1",
"angular-mocks": "1.4.14",
"angular-pnotify": "0.1.2",
"angular-recaptcha": "4.2.0",
"angular-resource": "1.4.7",
"angular-route": "1.3.20",
"angular-sanitize": "1.3.15",
"angular-translate": "2.6.1",
"angular-translate-loader": "1.6.2",
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.18.1",
"angular-translate-loader-url": "2.18.1",
"angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.18.1",
"angular-translate-storage-local": "2.18.1",
"angular-ui-bootstrap": "2.5.6",
"angular-ui-mask": "1.8.7",
"angular-websocket": "2.0.1",
"angular-xeditable": "0.10.0",
"angularfire": "2.3.0",
"bootstrap": "3.4.1",
"bootstrap-submenu": "2.0.3",
"bootstrap-timepicker": "0.5.2",
"cheet.js": "0.3.3",
"clipboard": "1.5.10",
"clone": "2.1.2",
"config": "3.1.0",
"core-js": "^3.6.4",
"d3": "5.16.0",
"dicom-parser": "1.0.2",
"es6-promise-promise": "^1.0.0",
"es6-templates": "0.2.3",
"firebase": "4.5.1",
"font-awesome": "4.4.0",
"forever-agent": "0.6.1",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
"html5-boilerplate": "7.2.0",
"javascript-detect-element-resize": "0.5.3",
"jquery": "2.1.4",
"jquery-deparam": "0.5.2",
"jquery-mousewheel": "3.1.12",
"jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
"jquery-sticky-kit": "1.1.3",
"jquery-ui": "1.13.2",
"jscroll": "2.4.1",
"jstz": "2.1.1",
"lodash": "4.17.21",
"ment.io": "0.9.23",
"moment": "2.29.4",
"moment-timezone": "0.5.34",
"moment-timezone-utils": "0.0.1",
"ng-animate": "0.3.4",
"ng-country-select": "0.1.4",
"ng-file-upload": "12.2.13",
"ng-img-crop": "https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop/archive/v0.3.2.tar.gz",
"ng-password-strength": "0.3.0",
"ngImgCrop": "https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop/archive/v0.3.2.tar.gz",
"ngclipboard": "2.0.0",
"ngmap": "1.18.5",
"normalize-path": "3.0.0",
"oauthio-web": "0.6.2",
"oclazyload": "1.1.0",
"opentok": "2.12.1",
"opentok-angular": "2.1.2",
"opentok-layout-js": "3.7.1",
"opentok-token": "1.1.1",
"owl.carousel": "2.2.0",
"pdfjs-dist": "2.12.313",
"phoneformat": "0.0.7",
"phoneformat.js": "1.0.9",
"pnotify": "3.0.1",
"randexp": "0.4.3",
"request": "2.88.0",
"spark-md5": "3.0.0",
"textangular": "1.5.16",
"timepicker": "1.11.15",
"tough-cookie": "3.0.1",
"tunnel-agent": "0.6.0",
"ui-select": "0.11.2",
"utf-8-validate": "5.0.2"
}
}

[Expected Behaviour]
After a route change in the AngularJS application, the page should not reload since it is single page application.

[Actual Behaviour]
The page reloads twice on every route change, causing unexpected behavior and affecting the user experience.
The page reloads on every route change, causing unexpected behaviour and affecting the user experience.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.